# MongoDB - Check if value exists for a field in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where the document looks like below:

```
/* 0 */

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5320b1c723bc746084fa7107"),
    "channels" : [ 
        3, 
        4
    ]
}


/* 1 */

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5320b1c723bc746084fa7107"),
    "channels" : [ ]
}
```

I want to form a query such that I want all documents where channels has some value and is not empty.

I tried this:

```
db.event_copy.find({"channels":{$exists:true}})
```

But that will still return me the documents with no values in channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it using this :

```
db.event_copy.find({'channels.0' : {$exists: true}}).count()
```

Comment: does it check also if the field has a value or only if the field exists?

Answer (score 17):

You need the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator. To find something with **no** elements do the following

```js
db.collection.find({ channels: {$size: 0} })
```

If you know you have a fixed size then do that

```js
db.collection.find({ channels: {$size: 2} })
```

Otherwise reverse that with [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)

```js
db.collection.find({ channels: {$not:{$size: 0}} })
```

And you can combine with [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

```js
db.collection.find({ $and: [ 
    { channels: {$not:{$size: 0}} },
    { channels: {$exists: true } }
]})
```

Comment: Yes I just tried the $size operator. The problem is I want all documents which have some value in it. I do not how many values might be inside it. Basically I don't know the size. I tried using the $gte with $size and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @PiHorse You can't do ranges but there is a condition for that. See edit.

Comment: For some reason that query doesn't give me the correct results. It also returns the documents which don't have the channels field itself.

Comment: @PiHorse You need to specify things like that when you ask your questions. See the edit again.

Comment: That would work fine. But look at the answer i posted. That seems to be as a more simpler solution. Not sure of the query performance though.

Comment: @PiHorse the dot notation method is fine and is the first thing that comes to mind when some documents may not even have the field.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the size operator [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/)

```
db.event_copy.find( { channels: { $size: 0 } } );
```

Comment: Yes I just tried the $size operator. The problem is I want all documents which have some value in it. I do not how many values might be inside it. Basically I don't know the size. I tried using the $gte with $size and it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['my_database']
col=db['my_collection']

### Input
email="test@gmail.com"
########
exist_count=col.find({"email": email},{'_id':0}).count()

if exist_count>=1:
    print("Field value is present")
else:
    print("Field value is not present")
```