# How can I check if particular value exists using Java driver 3.6+ mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have documents like:

[image]

My [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057651/how-can-i-check-whether-a-field-exists-or-not-in-mongodb) is `Document query = new Document("sent", new Document("$exists", true));`
Now I can check only if field exists, but I want to check if exists value of this field.

For example: if my document has field and value `sent:true`, then I need to do something.

As I understand, it would similar to this:

```
Document query =  new Document(...);

if(query) {
//to do something
}
```

UPD:
[image]

Comment: And I checked [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367812/8370915) from here, but it's a bit weird, because this example doesn't seem as checking value, only field.

Comment: can't you just use a `find` query and , e.g. `.find(eq("sent", true))` and use a `limit(1)` as well ?

Comment: @AKSW, good advice, thanks, but how can I check then? I updated my question.

Comment: Like any other Java `Iterable` I'd say? Make use of `hasNext()`

Comment: @AKSW, `FindIterable` doesn't have methods like `next()`, `hasNext()`, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if particular value exists, you can use method [count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db.collection.count) with [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#eq) operator:

```
 long count = collection.count(new Document("sent", new Document("$eq", true)));

 if (count < 5) { // if the number of documents less than 5 has value as true
 // then to do something
 }
```

If you want to check just existing field than you need to use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) operator:

```
long count = collection.count(new Document("sent", new Document("$exists", true)));

 if (count < 5) { // if the number of documents less than 5 has field named as sent
 // then to do something
 }
```